# Android NDK test app using OpenSL ES

Tags: android-ndk, opensl

I have developped a NDK applicaiton (which I am running from console) and running on a TI AM37x hardware using Android 4.0.3. This application is using OpenSL API's and I am trying to play the song from SDCard on the hardware. Same path is working with the NDK sample code (URI playback), but I am unable to hear audio from my app. Does any one have any idea?
My code flow looks like:

```cpp
    result=slCreateEngine(&engineObject, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ....
    result = (*engineObject)->Realize(engineObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
    ....
    result = (*engineObject)->GetInterface(engineObject, SL_IID_ENGINE, &engineEngine);
    ....
    result = (*engineEngine)->CreateOutputMix(engineEngine, &outputMixObject, 1, ids, req);
    ....
    Realize, GetInterface ...
    ....
    SLchar path[] = "/mnt/sdcard/Audio/Msong.mp3" ;
    SLDataLocator_URI loc_uri = {SL_DATALOCATOR_URI, path};
    SLDataFormat_MIME format_mime = {SL_DATAFORMAT_MIME, NULL,   
    SL_CONTAINERTYPE_UNSPECIFIED};
    SLDataSource audioSrcuri = {&loc_uri, &format_mime};
    ...
    result = (*engineEngine)->CreateAudioPlayer(engineEngine, &uriPlayerObject, 
                                             &audioSrcuri,&audioSnkuri, 1, idsuri, requri);
    ...
    result = (*uriPlayerObject)->Realize(uriPlayerObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
    ...
    result = (*uriPlayerObject)->GetInterface(uriPlayerObject, SL_IID_PLAY, 
                                                                  &uriPlayerPlay);
    ...
    result = (*uriPlayerObject)->GetInterface(uriPlayerObject, SL_IID_SEEK, 
                                                                   &uriPlayerSeek);
    ...
    result = (*uriPlayerPlay)->SetPlayState(uriPlayerPlay, SL_PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure audioSnk

```
// create output mix
const SLInterfaceID ids[1] = {SL_IID_ENVIRONMENTALREVERB};
const SLboolean req[1] = {SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE};
result = (*engineEngine)->CreateOutputMix(engineEngine, &outputMixObject, 1, ids, req);

// realize the output mix
result = (*outputMixObject)->Realize(outputMixObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
```

...

```
// configure audio sink
SLDataLocator_OutputMix loc_outmix = {SL_DATALOCATOR_OUTPUTMIX, outputMixObject};
SLDataSink audioSnk = {&loc_outmix, NULL};
```